# Transition for the pointer-events not working

Tags: css, css-transitions, pointer-events

I need help with transition for the pointer events.
I have hidden popups on the website that appear once the user clicks the add button, edit button or one of the photos, and I coded them to appear in transition.
I tried to disable the cursor from the css code until the popup transition is over with the transition property on the pointer events.
But when i tried to implement that it didn’t work and the only way i could achieve this effect is through JS with a listener on the transition end, but my code reviewer noted I can achieve it through css.
After checking online for a solution and also checking all the animatable properties in css i came to a conclusion that the cursor point property can’t be transitioned.
I tried to transition it with steps and with timing-delay but without any success, i might have missed something but i am trying to solve it for 2 days without any leads on the solution.
Thanks

link to my GitHub repository - https://github.com/yaniv10501/web_project_4.git

css for the popup (I made the transition 6sec long so I can easily check if the code works or not) -

```
.popup {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 6s ease-in-out, opacity 6s ease-in-out, pointer-events 6s steps(1, end);
  -o-transition: visibility 6s ease-in-out, opacity 6s ease-in-out, pointer-events 6s steps(1, end);
  transition: visibility 6s ease-in-out, opacity 6s ease-in-out, pointer-events 6s steps(1, end);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  content: ' ';
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The JS code for the cursor disable (commented in the code) -

```
function cursorDisable(popup) {

  popup.addEventListener("transitionend", function(currentPopup) {

    if (popup != currentPopup.target) return;

    else {

      popup.style.pointerEvents = "visible";

      page.style.pointerEvents = "auto"

    }

  });

  popup.addEventListener("transitionrun", function() {

    page.style.pointerEvents = "none";

  });

};
```